# React: Search Results not being displayed?

Tags: javascript, search, reactjs

So I am learning react.js, and I am developing a quick search engine using the GitHub API of users.

The API side of the project works fine (I have tested by manually entering names into the area)

Its the search build in react that is not working.

(FYI: I am using Plunker which has react support)

***script.jsx***

```
var Card = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return{};
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    var component = this;
    $.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + this.props.login, function(data){
      component.setState(data);
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
       <img src={this.state.avatar_url} width="100"/>
       <h3>{this.state.name}</h3>
       <hr/>
      </div>
      );
  }
});

var Form = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var loginInput = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.login);
    this.props.addCard(loginInput.value);
    loginInput.value = '';
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input placeholder="Enter Github Name" ref="login"/>
      <button>Search</button>
      </form>
      );
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {logins: []};
  },
  addCard: function(loginToAdd){
    this.setState({logins: this.state.logins.concat(loginToAdd)});
  },
  render: function() {
    var cards = this.state.logins.map(function(login){
      return (<Card login={login} />);
    });
    return(
      <div>
       <Form addCard={this.addCard} />
       {cards}
      </div>
      )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: a link to the plunkr will be useful

Comment: What results are you expecting, what results are you getting?

Comment: @jzm heres the plunker link sry  -https://plnkr.co/edit/T7Xm92j20wRzatyx6Uyh?p=info

Comment: @DavidGilbertson it should be the name and the github picture, each time a new user is search it is added below the previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was (if you check console), that you had a duplicate script tag in the `<head>` which you didn't need. And also, you were doing React.findDOMNode instead of ReactDOM.findDOMNode

Line 25 of your JSX file:

```
var loginInput = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.login);
```

That said, you don't need to do `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`. You can just use `this.refs.login`